# Lift IO exception into MonadError with automatic mapping

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function which will map `IO` exceptions into `MonadError e m` with a helper class, `Injection`. However GHC has trouble deducing `Exception e10` constraint (?) in the following example:

```hs
#!/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
build-depends: base
             , mtl
default-extensions: FlexibleInstances
                  , MultiParamTypeClasses
                  , ScopedTypeVariables
-}

import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad.Except

main :: IO ()
main =
  putStrLn $ "hello cabal"


class Injection a b where
  inject :: a -> b

instance Injection a a where
  inject = id


try' :: forall m e1 e2 a. (MonadIO m, Exception e1, MonadError e2 m, Injection e1 e2) => IO a -> m a
try' x = do
  r <- liftIO (try x)
  case r of
    Left (e :: e1) -> throwError $ (inject e :: e2)
    Right a -> pure a
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Main.hs:24:9: error:
    • Could not deduce (Exception e10)
      from the context: (MonadIO m, Exception e1, MonadError e2 m,
                         Injection e1 e2)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   try' :: forall (m :: * -> *) e1 e2 a.
                           (MonadIO m, Exception e1, MonadError e2 m, Injection e1 e2) =>
                           IO a -> m a
        at Main.hs:24:9-100
      The type variable ‘e10’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘try'’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In the type signature:
        try' :: forall m e1 e2 a.
                (MonadIO m, Exception e1, MonadError e2 m, Injection e1 e2) =>
                IO a -> m a
   |
24 | try' :: forall m e1 e2 a. (MonadIO m, Exception e1, MonadError e2 m, Injection e1 e2) => IO a -> m a
   |
```

How can I write `try'` function?

Comment: I suspect that when you write `Left (e :: e1)`, this binds a *new* type variable named `e1`, unrelated to the existing in-scope one. Try `Left e -> throwError $ (inject (e :: e1) :: e2)`, maybe?

Comment: ...you're gonna have a lot of pain even if you get `try'` working, though. For example, you won't be able to write any other instances for `Injection`. What made you want this design? Maybe we can suggest a more idiomatic way.

Comment: @DanielWagner shouldn't `ScopedTypeVariables` make `e1` unequivocal in this case? Your suggestion with `(inject (e :: e1) :: e2)` results in the same error. This `Injection` class is just simplified `Control.Monad.Except.CoHas`. The idea is to be able to bridge between GHC exceptions and `MonadError` error handling, with the help of the class mapping one to the other. In principle this should give you also possibility to build some kind of exception hierarchy.

Comment: Bleh. I wasn't thinking straight when I wrote my previous two comments, both are just wrong. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the type:

```
try' :: forall m e1 e2 a.
    (MonadIO m, Exception e1, MonadError e2 m, Injection e1 e2) =>
    IO a -> m a
```

When you go to *use* `try'`, the absolute maximum information that can be provided to the type inference engine by the way it's used is to specify `a` and `m` -- because `e1` and `e2` do not appear in the body of the type. There is a functional dependency in the `MonadError` class that says that knowing `m` also fixes `e2`. But `e1` is left floating -- there may be many types that are instances of `Exception` and can be injected into `e2`, and the compiler doesn't know which one you want!

These days, with `TypeApplications`, you can explicitly supply type arguments. If you are okay with having all users explicitly annotate their choice of types for `e1` at call sites, then you can apply the fix suggested in the error: turn on `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and away you go.